# Excel 2003(VBA) - Custom Identifier / Function / UDF

Tags: vba, excel-2003

I'm currently rewriting a small stock system for my work, and trying to speed up the program as it's dog slow and I have only been doing VBA for 2 weeks now.

In Excel 2003 Edition.

My issue (I think) is creating a identifier(s).

I have two and they are as follows:

```
   Dim QuickView As String
   QuickView = ActiveWorkbook.Range("a1:c200").Copy


   Dim Stock As String
   Stock = ActiveWorkbook.Range("c1:c200").Copy
```

My users currently select a file(WORKBOOK) from an open dialogue and I am importing the data in the ranges specified.

However, when I come to call these functions I get "Object does not support this property or method".

im unsure if this should be a UDF, as i can't see anywhere where you can write your own VBA function opposed to write a function in VBA for Excel to use.

Comment: It's not clear from your code exactly what you're trying to do, so you'll need to add some more details.  If you're trying to get the data from each range then you need to declare your variables as `Variant` and use `.Value` instead of `.Copy`.  That will give you a 2-D array in each case (even though your second range has only one column).

Answer (score 4):

In your two examples, both "QuickView" and "Stock" should be variants, not strings.

```
Dim Stock As Variant
Stock = ActiveWorkbook.Range("c1:c200").Copy
```

Remember, you do NOT need to assign ranges to a variable in order to copy (or cut) cell values to another location. Instead, you can do it like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c1:c200").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("c1")
```

The convention is `copy_from [SPACE] put_it_here`.

Note: In my example above, the values would be copied into `Sheet1` of the workbook that contains the running code. The workbook running the VBA is always `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: In the first code sample, the `.Copy` part after `Range("c1:c200")` is irrelevant and should be removed. `Workbook` doesn't have a `Range` method so `ActiveWorkbook` should be replaced by `ActiveSheet` or, better, by a reference to a specific sheet. I've tidied up an obvious typo in the answer

Answer (score 1):

As @timbur said, you can copy a range without assigning it first. If you want to assign it, the variable must be of type Range (or Variant) and you must assign using Set, like any object assign.

```
Dim stock as Range  'or Variant, but Range is better
Set stock =  ActiveWorkSheet.Range("c1:c200")
'copy, and optionally paste at once
stock.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("c1")
```

Comment: There's no `Range` member in `Workbook` so a `Worksheet` reference will be needed here

Answer (score 1):

eSolved it guys, thanks for your answers :-D

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim FileOpened As Boolean ' Holds True or False value
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim MasterWorkbook As Workbook
Dim Row As Integer

' Remember the current workbook we are clicking the button from.
Set MasterWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook ' Use Set =  for all complex types.

' Identify file to open.
ChDrive "C:"
ChDir "c:\"

On Error Resume Next ' Temporarily ignore errors in situation when user says no to         opening the same master file a second time.
FileOpened = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show
On Error GoTo 0 ' Reinstates normal error reporting.

' Don't process the file if the user cancels the dialog.
If FileOpened Then

    ' The opened file automatically becomes the new active workbook and active worksheet.
Set SourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("c1:c394")

Set TargetRange = MasterWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("b1:b394")

' Copy cell values one at a time from the source range to the target range.
For Row = 1 To 394
    TargetRange.Cells(Row, 1).Value = SourceRange.Cells(Row, 1).Value
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close

' Set background colour of target range.
TargetRange.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With


' Tell Excel to recalculate only those formulas which use the target values.
TargetRange.Dirty

End If

End Sub
```

For those interested in this code :

User selects a file from nominated directory then selects the nominated range "c1:c394"  from that file and pasts it into the "sheet1".

Bypassing clipboard and updates any formulas affected by the added values.